# How to link a self written runtime when generating llvm-ir?

Tags: llvm

I'm currently working on a scheme compiler. At the moment im writing the runtime with the help of Boehm GC, with the goal to be able to call the functions from llvm-ir later on. What is the best way to link everything together in the end?

Currently I am building a static libary out of my C++ runtime which uses extern "C" in order to prevent name mangling.

Are there good examples which demonstrate how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate llvm-ir for your static library using clang++. Then link that with your compiler's output (i.e the llvm-ir from which you intend to call the library functions) using `llvm-link`. And you've got your final ir.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to create declarations for all of the primitives defined in my runtime? Because that is what I am doing right now, in order to look them up.

Comment: yes you have to. And remember to set their linkage to external